# How can mahalanobis and chi2-test be used to determine of an observation is acceptable?

Tags: statistical-significance, chi-squared-test, kalman-filter, observational-study, mahalanobis

Assume that you have a model

$$\dot x = Ax + Bu$$
$$y = Cx$$

And this model is SISO. Single input and single output. You got the mission to determine of an observation is acceptable for the kalman filter.

What does that mean? What is the observation?

The tools you need to use to accept the observation is mahalanobis distance and chi2-test density function. But how can those tools be used to determine if an observation is acceptable?

**Example**

Assume that you are measuring a distance to a wall.

[image]

Then suddenly something happens. The measurement tool that you are using measure the other side of the wall, just because your current wall was more smooth than the first wall, due to noise.

[image]

But the millisecond later, the mesurement tool went back to normal. The noise was only temporary.